# How to dynamically set value while initializing model in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I want to set the `in_features` parameter in the Linear layer, but I want to dynamically set it while initializing the model. Because I will be getting that value in the `forward` function.

```py
class SimpleModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_channels, graph_feats):
        super().__init__()
        self.convs = torch.nn.ModuleList(.....)
        ......
        ......
        self.dense = torch.nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(graph_feats + (18 * x), 128),
                                         nn.ReLU(),
                                         nn.Linear(128, 128),
                                         nn.ReLU(),
                                         nn.Linear(128, 64),
                                         nn.ReLU(),
                                         nn.Linear(64, 1),
                                        )

    def forward(self, x_cfg: Tensor,x_feat: Tensor, x_op: Tensor, edge_index: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        x = torch.concat([x_feat,self.embedding(x_op)],dim = 1)
       
        for conv in self.convs:
            x = conv(x, edge_index).relu()
        x_graph = torch.mean(x,0)

        x_cfg = torch.flatten(x_cfg, start_dim=1)
        x = torch.concat([x_cfg, x_graph.repeat((len(x_cfg),1))],axis=1)


        x = torch.flatten(self.dense(x))
        return x

model = SimpleModel(hidden_channels = [32, 64,128, 128, 64], graph_feats = 256).to(device)
```

The variable `x_cfg` has a shape of `(100000, 40, 18)`. After flattening the last 2 dim `(100000, 720)`. I want to use this `40` value and put in that `x` value in `self.dense` while initializing. On the other hand, this `40` is not constant. I don't know if it is even doable in PyTorch or not.

How can I achieve this? Or is there any alternative easier way to approach?